# Array to json convert in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5, php-7

i have this array

```
    array:82 [
  1000 => array:10 [
    "id" => 1000
    "name" => "name"
    "name2" => "name2"
    "name3" => "name3"
],
....
]
```

how to convert array to this json format ?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1000",
      "name1": "name",
      "name2": "name2",
      "name3": "name3"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

i try this but not work

```
$tableData = array();
$tableData['data'] = array_map(function($session) {
    return [$session['id'],$session['name'],$session['name2']];
}, $response);
 return response()->json($tableData);
```

anybody have idea?

i need this for datatable respons

Comment: What is `$response`?  I noticed you tagged the question with Laravel, is it an Eloquent collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$tableData = array();

foreach($session as $sess){
  $tableData['data'][] = ["id"=>$sess['id'],"name"=>$sess['name'],"name2"=>$sess['name2'],"name3"=>$sess['name3']];
}
return json_encode($tableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `json_encode()` function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php